# Can't login to MySQL after Yosemite update

Tags: mysql

Let me start by saying that i've looked through tons of posts (both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) and [elsewere](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/) on the [internet](http://innovativethought.net/2007/05/17/resetting-your-forgotten-mysql-password/)) about resetting the mysql password, but nothing seems to work for me. Oh, i'm also fairly new to working on the command line.

Last week i updated my osx to Yosemite and when i tried to update the Apache settings today i noticed i couldn't connect to MySQL anymore. Before the update everything was working fine (MySQL had a password, which i knew and worked), so i have no idea what happened. The strange thing is that i updated another (older) laptop to Yosemite as well and on that one MySQL works fine now.

When i open phpmyadmin i can't login. The saved password (from before the update, which worked on Mavericks) doesn't seem to work anymore.

Below what i tried on the command line (with and without first starting/stopping MySQL (in safe mode)):

```
mysql root
#Gives me: ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'root'

mysql -u root
#Gives me: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysql -u root -p
#Gives me: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I can use the `mysql` command, which gets me

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Trying to update the password here gets me the following

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'
mysql>
```

I really hope someone knows what could be the problem, because i'm out of options

I used [this article](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/) as a reference for updating the Apache settings

**Edit:**
Additional information after Tata's comment

That comment gives me `-bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory`.

Also `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` gives me:

```
141102 18:11:26 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
141102 18:11:26 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

After that, i still can't do anything.

Unfortunately i don't know where to find the mysql init script and what to modify.

### Solution

I've found a solution via [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/641590/reset-mysql-password-doesnt-work-cant-connect-without-granted-tables-on-osx/641592#641592). I forgot that i've added an `com.mysql.mysql.plist` file that i loaded via `launchctl` on startup to autostart MySQL on startup. First doing a `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist` stopped MySQL and let me login in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working you need to start your mysql server with --skip-grant-tables parameter.

```
 /etc/init.d/mysqld restart --skip-grant-tables
```

check this link for more information

[B.5.4.1 How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

It's also possible that your init script does not transfer the additional parameters to the mysqld_safe process. You should check it in the process list.

Comment: Thanks, but i've tried that already. I've edited my post with additional information